# ZF2 deleteAction not working

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2, sql-delete

```
public function deleteAction() {

    $id = (int) $this->params()->fromRoute('id',0);
    if (!$id) {
        return $this->redirect()->toRoute('studfood');
    }

    $request = $this->getRequest();
    if ($request->isPost()) {
        $del = $request->getPost('del', 'No');

        if ($del == 'Yes') {
            $id = (int) $request->getPost('id');

            $this->getRezepteTable()->deleteRezepte($id);   
        }

        return $this->redirect()->toRoute('studfood');
    }

    return array(
            'id'         => $id,
            'studfood'   => $this->getRezepteTable()->getRezepte($id)
    ); }
```

As you can see that is my deleteAction in my "RezepteController". I actually copied the album tutorial from zend2.

```
namespace Studfood\Model;

       use Zend\Db\TableGateway\TableGateway;
       use Studfood\Model\Rezepte;
       use Zend\Db\Sql\Sql;
       use Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter;

class RezepteTable {

protected $tableGateway;

public function __construct(TableGateway $tableGateway) {

    $this->tableGateway = $tableGateway;
}
public function deleteRezepte($id) {

        if($id != 0) {
        $this->tableGateway->delete(array('id' => (int) $id)); }
        else { throw new \Exception('id = 0'); }
    } }
```

And thats my RezepteTable with the database command in it.

So my problem is that if i want to Delete something and press on the button "Yes", nothing happens. Thats why I added this Exception to the RezepteTable. And I always get the id=0 Exception.

The only difference from the tutorial is, that i added more tables to my project with Forgein Keys in it. (fetchall with joints etc.).

```
 <?php
 use Studfood\Model\Rezepte;

 $name = 'Rezepte loeschen';
 $this->headTitle($name);
 ?>
 <h1><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($name); ?></h1>

 p>Are you sure that you want to delete
 '<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($rezepte->name); ?>'?
 </p>
 <?php
 $url = $this->url('studfood', array(
 'action' => 'delete',
 'id'     => $this->id,
  ));
   ?>
   <form action="<?php echo $url; ?>" method="post">
    <div>
 <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo (int) $rezepte->id; ?>" />
 <input type="submit" name="del" value="Yes" />
 <input type="submit" name="del" value="No" />
  </div>
  </form>
```

And thats finally my delete View.

So what happens is following:

1. I press on the button Delete on the row i want to delete.
2. I press on Yes [Delete1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qZQuW.png)
3. I get following Error because of the Exception in deleteRezepte[Delete2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0zSKF.png)

Without the Exception it will just redirect me to my main page.

So i have no clue where my error is. Somebody got any idea?

Much appreciated.

Comment: `echo $rezepte->id` in your view should be `echo $studfood->id` to match the name of the variable passed from the controller. You might also want to check if the record can be loaded first (before `isPost()`) as you would get a similar issue.

Comment: What is the `id` routing you are using (the url)? Also, why do you get the $id from route, then from the post params?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get id from post. Can you not use id from route?

In your view you use two different ways to output id `$this->id` and `$rezepte->id`. Are you sure both contain the correct value?

I think you should check the `value` on the hidden `id` field in your form?